# Google chrome pagespeed optimized images

Tags: pagespeed, google-pagespeed

Can I use images optimized using Pagespeed for Chrome freely in a public website? Is their usage restricted by any mean (license)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes... all pagespeed is doing is optimising the existing images - Google don't claim copyright over them because you ran it through their tool.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. The PageSpeed codebase is governed by the Apache 2.0 license. https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/faq#license

If you want to optimise yourself, you can use jpegtran or pngcrush. Similar benefits.